# How to execute button by clicking on another button java?

Tags: java, click, mouse, execute, jbutton

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
// File Menu
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(fileMenu);
// File->New
JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
newMenuItem.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        btnExample.setText("Clicked");
        btnExample.doClick();
    //---------->SOME HOW TO EXECUTE btnExample<---------//
}
});
fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

final JButton btnExample = new JButton("SD");
frame.getContentPane().add(btnExample, "cell 4 0,growx,aligny top");
btnExample.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    spinnerForVar.setValue(4);//default value for spinner
    spinnerForFunc.setValue(4);//default value for spinner
    ...             
  }
});
```

Hello! I hope someone can help me. Here it is the problem: I have Menu item "New" and have button btnExample. I want the following: When i click on "File->New" it executes btnExample. My code is able only to change the button title and show visual affect of clicking. But how can I actually  execute it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have only one advice - don't do that. Don't bind GUI components in this way.

If you want two components to execute the same operation, simply pack this operation in a method and call the method from both components.

Also, use ActionListener - are you sure the user is going to press it using mouse and not keyboard? what if you add shortcuts to those buttons/components?

Comment: @alexey, It may work, but it is not the best solution. Swing was designed to use Actions. The "shared method" this reply is talking about should be the Action, not a method you add to your class.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //My button to click on it

    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);//this is the call for the other button to execut it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a MouseListener for this.

You should be using Actions. Then you can add the Action to both the JButton and the JMemuItem.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Answer (score 0):

Amazing, I found my solution in your codes!

```
        btnExample.doClick();
```

This did the job for me